# Yosys instruction "sat -dump_cnf "

Tags: sat, yosys, cnf

I have a sample combinatorial circult in Verilog where I can follow the instruction to do logic synthesis and generate blif file.

However, what I need is to generate the CNF formula out of the circuit. Tools such as ABC only allows to generate from combinatorial miter (i.e., with 1 output).

I tried the yosys instruction "sat -dump_cnf FILE", and indeed I am able to generate a CNF file. However, I am not sure how to map variables in the CNF with I/Os in the circuit.

Have anyone studied the feature "sat -dump_cnf" from Yosys and can give me a pointer?

Comment: Can you post a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for what you are trying to do? How do you specify your properties? As Verilog assertionsa nd assumptions? `sat -dump_cnf` is definitely not what you are looking for. Maybe `miter -assert`? Or maybe `write_aiger`? I can post a complete answer when you have clarified what it is you are trying to do..